# Chart.js Label Issue

Tags: javascript, chart.js, ejs

So I am making a COVID-19 tracker(For Indian region) web Application using Node.js Express.js and EJS. So the issue i am getting is while creating Chart using library chart.js And I am using this API to fetch data https://api.covid19india.org/data.json .And the chart is for Total Confirmed cases on Y-axis and on X-axis Date (date from the starting of this pandemic till now)
these Informations are fetched from the api .I'm using a for loop to iterate through the array and get the specific data and pusshing it into an empty array `dailyDateChnage=[], dailyCnf=[];`
and later passing this data into the EJS file analytics.ejs `<%=dailyDateChnage%> <%=dailyCnf%>`

```js
const dailyDateChange=[],dailyCnf=[];

const url = "https://api.covid19india.org/data.json";

const covidDataApi = axios.get(url).then(function(response) {
  covidData = response.data;
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < covidData.cases_time_series.length; i++) {
    let day = covidData.cases_time_series[i].date;
    let cnf = covidData.cases_time_series[i].totalconfirmed;
    
    dailyDateChange.push(day);
      dailyCnf.push(cnf);
      
  }
  
 app.get("/analytics", function(req, res) {


  res.render("analytics", {
    dailyDateChange: dailyDateChange,
    dailyCnf: dailyCnf,

  });

});
```

my code for creating a chart using chart.js in file analytics.ejs

```html
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

 
<script>


var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

    type: 'line',
    data:{
      labels:[<%=dailyDateChange%>],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Daily Confirmed Cases',

            data: [<%=dailyCnf%>],
            fill:false,
            backgroundColor: [
                "red"
            ],
            borderColor: [
               "red"
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
            pointBorderColor:"red",
          pointBackgroundColor:"red",

        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

labels:<%=dailyDateChange%> using this label the chart is not rendering  [here is an image of the source page the data is being sent but not being rendered[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQpGe.png)  [and an image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLkmD.png)
but when replacing the labels as labels:<%=dailyCnf%>, the chart is getting rendered. [image after replacing the labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCEyE.png)

And I have tried converting the date data to string and Converting the date data to millisecond the again converting it to string 
nothing has worked for me.
I don't even understand what is this issue
Can someone Explain and provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When printing `dailyDateChange` using `<%= %>` it simply "prints" it as output. Consider this: You use console.log with a string element - you don't get double quotes around it in the output.

But in your code, you want the double quotes around the values of label.

Currently you might be getting something like this:

```
labels: [10 April, 11 April]
```

While you need this:

```
labels: ["10 April", "11 April"]
```

The simplest method to do so is convert it via `JSON.stringify` and use <%- %>` instead. The - tag (instead of =) does not escapes the string.

This code should work for you:

```
labels: <%- JSON.stringify(dailyDateChange) %>
```

Note that I also removed [] from around label as Stringify does that for us.